# Compare CSV rows to a database

Tags: perl

I have to compare a Database from a CSV file.
The database is filled with the same CSV by a script i made.

The case is that occasionally their will be rows added or removed from the CSV file and the script has to run again.
When this happens it has to check if their where any changes compared to the Database.

I hope you guys can help.

What i've tried.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use DBI;
 $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:perltest','root','password')
 or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
 $sql = "select * from samples";
 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute
 or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
 while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
 $I1 = @row[1];
 }

$CSVSep=",";#separator in csv file
$dbh=DBI->connect(qq{DBI:CSV:csv_sep_char=$CSVSep});#create connection to csv file
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'test'}={'file'=>$TMP_Path,'eol'  => "\n"};#Connect the file
my$csv=$dbh->prepare(" SELECT * FROM test");# Get all rows in the csv file
$csv->execute();

while(my @UploadFileLineSplit = $csv->fetchrow_array){
$I2 = @UploadfileLineSplit[1];
}

if ($I1 == $I2){
print "Their Both the Same";
}

else{
print "Their Both Different!";
}
```

Comment: Clarification needed: What is your expected result? Changed / Not Changed? If yes, perform a checksum on both side then you'll know. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: The only thing i want is some guidance on how to compare a DB with the CSV. The outcome has to be something like if changed print Changed! and visa versa.
I've tried reading out both the DB and CSV and then compering the two arrays (did not work).

Comment: "did not work" is vague, can you show your codes?

Comment: Ye sure give me a sec

Comment: Added it in the original post.

Comment: You can't make it this way, `$I1` and `$I2` change in every while loop, but your checking `if` clause only executes once. In this way, you only check the last row of each database / dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rely on row keys and extract two groups of them (where `A` are keys from CSV file and `B` are from mysql table)

1. `keys from CSV` except `keys from mysql`
2. `keys from mysql` except `keys from CSV`

Then the first group should be **inserted** into mysql, and second **deleted** from it.

[image]